# Mathematica reputation leagues are missing

Tags: discussion

I was randomly perusing the various pages under Users of the Mathematica.SE site when I realized that the reputation leagues point nowhere.

The link in question is: http://stackexchange.com/leagues/177/week/mathematica

Is this simply because this beta is so new that the guys over at SE haven't gotten around to creating them yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would assume that it's because this site is still in private beta. It doesn't really make sense to announce it on the Stack Exchange site until it's public. [The users page](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users) will list reputations in sorted order if you really want the information.

Comment: It's not terribly important for me. I was just curious because I had never seen the rep leagues before. I never knew it existed.